# React binding through constructor - possible to automate?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

As per recommendations from others, I have been binding class methods in the constructor in React, for example:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

I have components with many methods, and I am binding all of these methods to *this*.  Argh, what a pain!  To avoid repetitively maintaining this pattern, I built a function that would be called in the constructor in place of all the individual calls; it binds all the methods specific to that class, while a parent class would take care of its own methods moving up the classes.  For example:

```
function bindClassMethodsToThis(classPrototype, obj) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classPrototype).forEach(prop => {
        if (obj[prop] instanceof Function && prop !== 'constructor') {
            obj[prop] = obj[prop].bind(obj);
            console.log(`${classPrototype.constructor.name} class binding ${prop} to object`);
        }
    });
}

class A {
    constructor() {
        bindClassMethodsToThis(A.prototype, this);
    }

    cat() {
        console.log('cat method');
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        bindClassMethodsToThis(B.prototype, this);
    }

    dog() {
        console.log('dog method');
    }
}

let b = new B();
```

So, React and ES6 gurus, is this a reasonable approach, or I am doing something wrong here?  Should I stick to the individual bindings to *this*?

Comment: You can use simple arrow function syntax to auto-bind functions. so: instead of `cat() {`, do `cat = () => {`. then you don't need to bind in the constructor at all.

Comment: @Derek  Yep, that is another approach, and I like it.  But we're already going with bindings in the constructor and not the arrow functions.

Comment: You could also checkout [React-autobind](https://github.com/cassiozen/React-autobind) and see if it would be sufficient to your needs.

Comment: "*components with many methods, and I am binding all of these method*" - is that really necessary? Do you really use **all** of the methods as callbacks somewhere?

Comment: @Bergi good point, it's probably not necessary everywhere, but I'm following the pattern from others.  Using the function above, is there any harm in binding *this* to all of the class methods?

Comment: It does create unnecessarily many function objects, and thereby invalidates the advantages of `class` syntax method sharing. It's probably not harmful until you have millions of instances, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your strategy seems sound, though there are some edge cases that you may end up wanting to tackle. A library like [`react-autobind`](https://github.com/cassiozen/React-autobind), which [Alexander mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051197/react-binding-through-constructor-possible-to-automate#comment93002481_53051197), takes care of some of these things for you, and if I were to use this strategy I would probably use a library like this one (or take a look into the source code to get an idea for what it does).

For completeness, some alternative approaches are:

1. Use class properties and arrow functions (along with any necessary Babel transforms) to create pre-bound methods:

   ```js
   class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     handleChange = () => { /* ... */ }
   }
   ```
2. Use a decorator, like the [`autobind` decorator from core-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators#autobind), along with any necessary Babel transforms (this was the strategy I used previously):

   ```js
   import { autobind } from 'core-decorators'

   class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     @autobind
     handleChange() { /* ... */ }
   }
   ```
3. Explore the use of [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (currently in alpha) to avoid the problem of binding all together (since state values and setters exists as local variables to be closed over). This is the strategy I've been preferring very recently, but please note it is still in the proposal state and may change. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Babel setup for it, you can also use arrow functions instead, avoiding the need to bind `this`:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: @Derek pointed that out above.  We are not going with that option, although I do like it overall.  Our methods are declared without the arrow functions, and our standard is do the bindings in the constructor.

Comment: It's not just arrow functions you are using here, it's also class properties.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this is to call bind in render:

onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}